# Exceptions at renaming a column in Laravel 5.1 DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, exception, pdo

i just did a migration in Laravel. I noticed that in the users table there are several columns: id, name, email and so on. I changed the the column named "name" to "username" and i put it as a unique column. Now when I start my app and try to register i get 2 exeptions: QueryExpetion and PDOExeption. I thought that I should change something in the Builder.php bou there is no such thing in there. These are the error I got. What do I need to change?!

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 651: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `name` = kosach)

in Connection.php line 651
at Connection->runQueryCallback('select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `name` = ?', array('kosach'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 611
at Connection->run('select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `name` = ?', array('kosach'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 324
at Connection->select('select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `name` = ?', array('kosach'), true) in Builder.php line 1406
at Builder->runSelect() in Builder.php line 1383
at Builder->get(array('*')) in Builder.php line 1718
at Builder->aggregate('count', array('*')) in Builder.php line 1638
at Builder->count() in DatabasePresenceVerifier.php line 57
at DatabasePresenceVerifier->getCount('users', 'name', 'kosach', null, null, array()) in Validator.php line 1070
at Validator->validateUnique('name', 'kosach', array('users'), object(Validator)) in Validator.php line 362
at Validator->validate('name', 'unique:users') in Validator.php line 314
at Validator->passes() in Validator.php line 335
at Validator->fails() in RegistersUsers.php line 32
at AuthController->postRegister(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AuthController), 'postRegister'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 256
at Controller->callAction('postRegister', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 164
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(AuthController), object(Route), 'postRegister') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 112
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php line 45
at RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RedirectIfAuthenticated), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(AuthController), object(Route), object(Request), 'postRegister') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 69
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController', 'postRegister') in Route.php line 203
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 704
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 706
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 671
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

1/2 PDOException in Connection.php line 319: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause'

```
in Connection.php line 319
at PDO->prepare('select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `name` = ?') in Connection.php line 319
at Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}(object(MySqlConnection), 'select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `name` = ?', array('kosach')) in Connection.php line 644
at Connection->runQueryCallback('select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `name` = ?', array('kosach'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 611
at Connection->run('select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `name` = ?', array('kosach'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 324
at Connection->select('select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `name` = ?', array('kosach'), true) in Builder.php line 1406
at Builder->runSelect() in Builder.php line 1383
at Builder->get(array('*')) in Builder.php line 1718
at Builder->aggregate('count', array('*')) in Builder.php line 1638
at Builder->count() in DatabasePresenceVerifier.php line 57
at DatabasePresenceVerifier->getCount('users', 'name', 'kosach', null, null, array()) in Validator.php line 1070
at Validator->validateUnique('name', 'kosach', array('users'), object(Validator)) in Validator.php line 362
at Validator->validate('name', 'unique:users') in Validator.php line 314
at Validator->passes() in Validator.php line 335
at Validator->fails() in RegistersUsers.php line 32
at AuthController->postRegister(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AuthController), 'postRegister'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 256
at Controller->callAction('postRegister', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 164
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(AuthController), object(Route), 'postRegister') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 112
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php line 45
at RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RedirectIfAuthenticated), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(AuthController), object(Route), object(Request), 'postRegister') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 69
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController', 'postRegister') in Route.php line 203
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 704
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 706
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 671
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: Without seeing some code, I'm going to assume that you are using the default `AuthController`. In it, you should have two methods `validator` and `create`. You need to change `name` to `username` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `AuthController` uses `name` for creating the user in the `create` method.

Change [this line](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8476df5c9eeb1489db64f7aa3456b38ae74d090d/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php#L60)'s key to `username`.

Comment: Yey, everything's perfect now. Thanks a milion again for helping me out for a second time!

Answer (score 1):

Well even though you’ve changed the name of the column in your database, it looks like somewhere in your code you’re still referencing `name`.